# Distributed File System for storing and retrieving

Tags: high-availability, distributed-filesystem

I require a highly available distributed file system where the documents of various types can be stored and retrieved and it should be able to scale horizontally. What would be the ideal choice for this? What should be the data layers that should be used on top of that for retrieving and inserting?

Comment: I am not sure what are you asking about. Do you have any specific problem related to programming? If you ask about favourite tool/library, or a recommendation, it's explicitly off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Because we are at programmers' site, you might want to look at MongoDB GridFS filesystem. It can be easily sharded and replicated, also has an easy to use API, is able to extend files with any meta-information, etc. But for usual filesystems its better to ask at [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) f.e.